# Report fraud websites online?

Tags: spam-prevention

There's an awful lot of scams going on, and I'd love to report them, but it seems that none of the big players (looking at you, Facebook, Twitter, YouTube) have a way to report external websites that are claiming to be these guys.

For instance, I just saw a website that pretends to be YouTube, presents a fake CAPTCHA, and the submit button triggers you clicking "like" which ends up posting it to your wall.

I could report to Imgur, which was hosting the images... but Facebook didn't seem to have anything to send this to, neither did YouTube. I don't run into spam every day, but when I do I'd sure like to help people get away from it.

What should I do?

Sitting on my hands is not an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can report to [Google Safe Browsing - Malware](http://www.google.com/safebrowsing/report_badware/) / [Phishing](http://www.google.com/safebrowsing/report_phish/) or use an addon like [Web of Trust](http://www.mywot.com/en/download).

Chrome & Firefox make use of Google Safe Browsing API, so reporting a fraudulent site to Safe Browsing will result in Chrome or Firefox displaying a message about an unsafe site.

Web of Trust(WOT) works in almost the same way.